# Drupal 7 - Issue in $head_title

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In my website I use different templates for each content type. 
I also use the metadata module.

When I display a node inside the page.tpl.php the $head_title variable is correct and takes the title of the metadata title.

The problem is that when I display a node that is being displayed through another template, the $head_title variable takes the default value.

The way that i chose from which template the node will be displayed is

```
if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
    // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "page--blog.tpl.php".
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $variables['node']->type  );
}
```

The $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] initially contains the array below

```
page__node
page__node__%
page__node__253
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: In which `preprocess` hook are you adding an extra `tpl` based on content type?

Comment: oops sorry into the function xxx_preprocess_page(&$variables) {}  
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way of doing. And the module you are talking about is `metadata` or `metatag`?

Comment: double fault, sorry.

I'm using the [metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag)

Comment: I've tested it locally on a Drupal 7 project with metatag module enabled and copy/pasted your `preprocess` code for the `tpl` ... but I don't have the issue. The $head_title (printed in `html.tpl.php`) is correct, the one I defined on my node.

Comment: You tried to use, for example the `code page--article.tpl` for the content type `code article`  by using the part of code that I have quoted to my question for the `code $variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` array?

Comment: Yes exactly. What you could do is verify in the `YOURTHEME_preprocess_html()` if the `$head_title` variable changes when adding a `theme_hook_suggestion`.

Comment: The `$head_title` is not available into the `YOURTHEME_preprocess_html`. I'm missing something? You can also check to the [official api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

Am I telling something wrong?

Comment: That is strange, $head_title is part of the html.tpl.php. You would be receiving php warnings if this variable is not available. Next thing to try is to disable the Metatag module and see if you still have the problem. Did you modified / create custom code for your theme ?

Comment: I know that the `$head_title` is a part of the `html.tpl.php` but as I can see/understand is **NOT** a part of the xxx_preprocess_html(). The strange thing is that the only difference between the page.tpl and the page--article.tpl.php is the main markup. The rest content of the file is the same exact, except the 'views' that are imported to the template with the same appropriate way to the all templates `render($page['text_container_banner'])`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was mine. I hadn't implement this `render($page['content']['metatags'])` to my template.